# How to Generate Date/Time in 2015-12-23T15:17:52.000Z Format with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I generate a date/time with JavaScript in this format:

```
2015-12-23T15:17:52.000Z
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: `new Date().toISOString()`

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking for. Do you want to format a given date value in the above format? Or do you want to convert such a string to a date value? It's not a shame if your question contains more than just one sentence.

Comment: This has already been solved many times over... look into http://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: Hi, new Date().toISOString() is what I was looking for thanks dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an ISO-formatted date, so use `toISOString`.

```
new Date().toISOString()
  "2015-12-23T15:50:18.134Z"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the new date function.

```
new Date();
```

Also, consider taking a look at momentJS for all your javascript date needs.